# How can I get the page title?

Tags: 8

`drupal_get_title()` has been removed from Drupal 8. How I can get the page title in Drupal 8?

Comment: This answer here below on this page works in Drupal 9.0.7: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/250205/1082

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you check the change records you should find the following: [drupal_set_title() and drupal_get_title() were removed](https://drupal.org/node/2067859).

You'll have to read the change notice for all of the info, but here is a starting point:

> **drupal_get_title()**
>
> As titles on routes now can be set on various ways (see above),
>   drupal_get_title() has been removed. In its place you should call the
>   title_resolver service.
>
> Drupal 7
>
> ```
> <?php
>   $title = drupal_get_title();
> ?>
> ```
>
> Drupal 8
>
> ```
> <?php
>   $request = \Drupal::request();
>   if ($route = $request->attributes->get(\Symfony\Cmf\Component\Routing\RouteObjectInterface::ROUTE_OBJECT)) {
>     $title = \Drupal::service('title_resolver')->getTitle($request, $route);
>   }
> ?>
> ```

Comment: The accepted response is out of date: see elsewhere in this thread for CurrentRouteMatch.

Answer (score 12):

As per [`batch_test.module` (D8.4)](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/drupal/-/blob/8.4.x/core/modules/system/tests/modules/batch_test/batch_test.module#L180-182) the following should work just fine:

> ```
> $request = \Drupal::request();
> $route_match = \Drupal::routeMatch();
> $title = \Drupal::service('title_resolver')->getTitle($request, $route_match->getRouteObject());
> ```

For more info see [`public function TitleResolver::getTitle`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Controller%21TitleResolver.php/function/TitleResolver%3A%3AgetTitle/8.4.x).

Comment: +1 Confirming this works with Drupal 9 (9.0.7), with node-based pages at least.  I'd expect it would work with non-node pages too but I haven't tried that yet.

Comment: @therobyouknow – You are welcome my friend! BTW I noticed you tagged the question with and additional version tag. Maybe read https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3640/15055 as an introduction regarding version tag usage and please try to avoid multiple version tags on the same post. Rather use none.

Comment: FYI - This approach doesn’t work on node edit pages.

Answer (score 3):

#### Note

The accepted response for this question is out of date: See [Request parameters, route name, and route object should be accessed via RouteMatch](https://www.drupal.org/node/2295317).

You should use the [*current_route_match*](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21core.services.yml/service/current_route_match/8.7.x) service to retrieve the current route, and then read or modify its parameters. This wraps any Symfony etc. magic.

In procedural code, you would use code similar to the following one.

```
$route = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getCurrentRouteMatch()->getRouteObject();
$title = $route->getDefault('_title');
```

In object-oriented code, you should use [dependency injection](http://www.jpstacey.info/blog/2016-10-13/drupal-8-api-services-and-dependency-injection-container) and inject the service.

Comment: What to do if there is no `$route->getDefault('_title');` but only a `$route->getDefault('_title_callback');`?

Comment: For example on http://example.com/user/1

Comment: This bypasses the TitleResolver so doesn't handle all situations. https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Controller%21TitleResolver.php/function/TitleResolver%3A%3AgetTitle/8.7.x

Comment: Using this solution will get the untranslated title.

Answer (score -3):

Drupal 8

```
$request = \Drupal::request();
  // Assuming the Request is $request.
  if ($request->attributes->has('_title')) {
    return $request->attributes->get('_title');
  }
```

Comment: I didn't mark this response down, but it looks like the `->get('_MAGIC')` method is unfortunately deprecated and mostly removed from D8: https://www.drupal.org/node/2124749

Answer (score -3):

In drupal 8 you can use $node->getTitle().

Comment: The issue with this answer is that the page you're on isn't necessarily a node.