# How do I show the current node title in page.html.twig OR in node.html.twig?

Tags: theming, 8

If I want to show the current node title in page.html.twig (by default it seems to only be available in node.html.twig) I have to create a preprocess function like so:

```
function theme_preprocess_page(&$variables, $hook) {
  // Set our page title so we can access it in page.html.twig
  if ($node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node')) {
    $variables['my_node_title'] = $node->title->value;
  }
}
```

And then I have to overwrite page-title.html.twig by copying it into my current theme folder and commenting out everything.

This doesn't seem "right".  Is there a better way?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The node is already available in the page template thanks to [`template_preprocess_page`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!includes!theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_page/8), so there's no need for the preprocess function. You can output the title with:

```
{{ node.label }}
```

The page title itself is a block, so if you don't need it any more just remove it from the region at /admin/structure/block. No need to copy the template to your theme or alter the original.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work on the front page, where `node` is just `NULL`. Is there a way to get any page title, including the front page title (even when a [title override](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33872400/857390) is used)?

Comment: That's correct @FlorianBrucker - unless the front page is a node, you wouldn't have a node variable available. The title is probably in `page['#title']`, I'm not sure if that would contain any override made by VIews (but probably)

Comment: @Clive Unfortunately, `page['#title']` is an empty string in `page.html.twig` over here.

Comment: Pity, I think that was valid at some point in the past, obviously not now. [This similar question](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/112757/how-can-i-get-the-page-title) might help

Comment: @Clive, thanks for the pointer but that didn't help me, either. I've posted [a question regarding the issue](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/193764/58028).

Comment: Worked fine for me when using node--[content-type-name].html.twig, I know the question is really about page.html.twig, but when "google-ing" for node.html.twig title brought me here.

Answer (score 3):

You can add below codes to top of `node.html.twig` in templates folder of your theme :

```
{% if not page %}
  <h2{{ title_attributes }}>
    <a href="{{ url }}" rel="bookmark">{{ label }}</a>
  </h2>
{% endif %}

{% if page %}
  <h2{{ title_attributes }}>
    {{ label }}
  </h2>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 2):

The Drupal 8 code for doing what the code you shown should do is the following one.

```
function theme_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  $request = \Drupal::request();
  $route_match = \Drupal::routeMatch();
  if ($route_match->getParameter('node')) {
    $page_title = \Drupal::service('title_resolver')->getTitle($request, $route_match->getRouteObject());
    $variables['my_node_title'] = $page_title;
  }
}
```