# Drupal 8 - how can I print a single field value in overridden field--node--title.html.twig template

Tags: theming

I created a content type "Troubleshooting Options". I want to render the title of this content in a different way. To do this I overrode default `field--node--title.html.twig` with `field--node--title--troubleshooting-options.html.twig` (as recommended by twig debug).

I am unable to render the `title` in this new template. Tried `{{ content.title }}`, `{{ node.title }}`, `{{ node.title.value }}` but none worked. Although drupal caching is disabled I rebuilt cache every time.

Twig file name suggestions:

```
<!-- FILE NAME SUGGESTIONS:
   * field--node--title--troubleshooting-options.html.twig
   x field--node--title.html.twig
   * field--node--troubleshooting-options.html.twig
   * field--title.html.twig
   * field--string.html.twig
   * field.html.twig
-->
<!-- BEGIN OUTPUT from 'core/themes/stable/templates/field/field--node--title.html.twig' -->
```

I am very new to Drupal.

Comment: You could instead create `node--[troubleshooting-options].html.twig` and then [use the code provided in this answer](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/187519/what-is-the-drupal-8-way-to-show-the-current-node-title-in-page-html-twig#answer-187520)

Comment: If I was to make a guess for your current template file, try `{{ items.title.content }}`

Comment: else try `{%- for item in items -%}
    {{ item.title.content }}
  {%- endfor -%}`